# UBUNTU Downgrade version

Tags: kernel, 22.04

I know that questions was asked before, but i'm afraid because isn't the sames version.
I did a big mistake when i tried to upgrade my version 20.04lts to 22.04lts. i tried to correct the error and i installed the verison "Ubuntu Kinetic Kudu (development branch)", and now i have the version 22.10 with kernel not "oem".

It's possible someone help me to downgrade to the version 22.04LTS with the kernel "oem" please?

Thanks in advance guys

best regards

Comment: No, it is not possible.

Answer (score 4):

It's not feasible to downgrade from a pre-alpha daily build of a development version of Ubuntu to an LTS version. The safer alternative is to do a fresh installation of Ubuntu 22.04.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to AskUbuntu Joca. 
Download 22.04 release of Ubuntu Linux.
Create a bootable USB. From `Windows` with `Balena Etcher`, `Rufus` or `Ventoy` for example. From `Linux` with `Startup Disk Creator` for example.
Boot from the USB-stick. Set this option in your BIOS/UEFI.
Once booted you see a welcome screen. This welcome screen has two options: “Try Ubuntu,” and “Install Ubuntu.” Choose the “Install Ubuntu” button.
Upon choosing “Install Ubuntu,” you’ll see the “Keyboard layout” window. In this window, select the keyboard layout you prefer, and click the “Continue” button.
Following the “Keyboard layout” page is the “Updates and other software” section. Use this page to select what type of installation you prefer (Normal or Minimal,) if you’d like to download updates while installing Ubuntu, and whether or not to install third-party software and drivers. Click “Continue” once you’ve chosen what to add to your Ubuntu installation.
After “Updates and other software” is the “Installation type” page. On this page, you can see several different installation types. As this guide focuses on downgrading a newer release of Ubuntu to an older release, you must select the “Erase Ubuntu 22.10 and reinstall” option. Then, after selecting this option, click “Continue” to move to the next page.
Note: the “Erase Ubuntu 22.10 and reinstall” will replace your 22.10 installation and partitions with an older 22.04 LTS installation, but all of your documents, apps, and other files will be gone.

Once you’ve made it past the “Installation type” section, follow the installer and choose your location (for time zone purposes,) create your username and set your password.
When the installation is complete, a message will appear on the screen. This message will let you know that the setup process is complete and that you should reboot your computer. You better shut off your computer though, remove the USB-stick and restart. Upon logging back in after rebooting, you’ll have successfully downgraded to an older release of Ubuntu.
If it does help you please accept the answer.